# Replacing DataFrame values with dictionary matches and a string for non-matches

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, append

I have DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame{'col1': ['afs', 'chk', 'est', 'app'],
 'col2': ['ofcr', 'guar', 'ltv', 'gender'],
 'col3': ['code', 'mod']}
```

And I have dictionary:

```
dict = {'ofcr':'officer','chk':'check','mod':'modification','est':'estimated','app':'application', 'gender':'gender'}
```

I need to iterate over df and replace mathing keys with their respective values. I can do this column by column with:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].map(dict)
```

But this converts non-matches to NaN. What I want is to leave the token unchanged, but add "-UNKNOWN-" or something similarly obvious to the string so it can be dealt with later. I've tried loops:

```
for tok in df['col1']:
    if tok in dict.values():
        df.replace(dict, inplace=True)
    if tok not in dict.values():
        df.replace(tok, tok '-UNKNOWN', inplace=True)
    print(tok)
```

This also replaced the matches (oddly enough in all columns, not just the one passed in) but didn't affect the non-matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['afs', 'chk', 'est', 'app'],
 'col2': ['ofcr', 'guar', 'ltv', 'gender'],
 'col3': ['code', 'mod', 'xxx', 'zzz']})

dct = {'ofcr':'officer','chk':'check','mod':'modification','est':'estimated','app':'application', 'gender':'gender'}

print(df.applymap(lambda x: dct.get(x, x + '-UNKNOWN')))
```

Prints:

```
          col1          col2          col3
0  afs-UNKNOWN       officer  code-UNKNOWN
1        check  guar-UNKNOWN  modification
2    estimated   ltv-UNKNOWN   xxx-UNKNOWN
3  application        gender   zzz-UNKNOWN
```

Comment: This is functional! It requires that I fill all empty values in the df creation with "xxx" or "zzz" or the like. But once done, I can I can remove the "xxx-UNKNOWN"s.

Answer (score 0):

After the map do this extra step:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].map(dict)
df["col1"] = df["col1"].fillna('-UNKNOWN')
```

Comment: I'm afraid that had no effect. I tried passing the df through a separate new dictionary {np.NaN: "-UNKNOWN"} but it just converted the entire df to NaN.

Comment: The new fillna, when used after the .map did indeed replace the NaNs per column with "-UNKNOWN". But what I want is to append the non-matches with "-UNKNOWN" rather than just replace them.